# Bash Script To Move Newest Specific File Type From Subdirectories

Tags: shell

- Searches all subdirectories from the current directory.
- Only targets specific file extension type.
- Copies only the newest file which has a time stamp in it's title to another directory.

  find . -mindepth 2 -name "*.ZIP" -exec cp {} tempZIP` \;

The only problem is I don't know how to tell it to grab only the newest file in each subdirectory. The files have the format:

2015-09-01_10-48-09.941+0000

```
for files in */; do

echo "Beginning of for loop"
echo "The current directory is $files"

cd $files
currentDirectory=$(pwd)
echo "Current working directory: $currentDirectory"

echo "Removing excess files from acqusition zips..."
rm *.csv *.tfr *.ini *.log
rm _Background.mca _Escape.mca _Gaussfit.mca _SumPeak.mca

echo "Removing the oldest MCA files..."
theDate=$(date +"LIVE_DATA_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.000+0000.MCA")
echo "The date timestamp is $theDate"


for file in *; do
  echo "Current file is: $file"

  file=${file/.[0-9][0-9][0-9]/}
  if [[ $theDate -gt $max ]] ; then
    max=$theDate
    latest="$file"
  fi
done
echo "Latest: $latest"

echo "Moving up a folder"
cd ../
movedDirectory=$(pwd)
echo "Moved directory $movedDirectory"

echo "End of for loop"
done
```

How do I do comparisons between the date format I've specified and the files?

```
The current directory is U-500.0.0.2015-09-01_10-49-01-34/
Current working directory: /Users/user/Desktop/WatsonErrorLogs/v448/AlloyScript/temp/U-500.0.0.2015-09-01_10-49-01-34
Removing excess files from acqusition zips...
rm: *.csv: No such file or directory
rm: *.tfr: No such file or directory
rm: *.ini: No such file or directory
rm: *.log: No such file or directory
rm: _Background.mca: No such file or directory
rm: _Escape.mca: No such file or directory
rm: _Gaussfit.mca: No such file or directory
rm: _SumPeak.mca: No such file or directory
Removing the oldest MCA files...
The date timestamp is LIVE_DATA_2015-09-08_11-31-59.000+0000.MCA
Current file is: LIVE_DATA_2015-09-01_10-49-04.446+0000.MCA
./test.sh: line 46: [[: LIVE_DATA_2015-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
Current file is: LIVE_DATA_2015-09-01_10-49-09.916+0000.MCA
./test.sh: line 46: [[: LIVE_DATA_2015-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
Latest: 
Moving up a folder
Moved directory /Users/user/Desktop/WatsonErrorLogs/v448/AlloyScript/temp
End of for loop
```

Comment: So .. this isn't a bash script.  The `find` command is not built in to bash.  Are you looking for a way to do this which avoids using `find`?

Comment: I don't mind using find. It just seems to make it difficult to iterate and use logic with find. I want to only pick the newest ZIP file in each sub directory. I'm not sure how to iterate and do comparisons of files in directories and subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to David's Linux-centric answer, here's one that should work in OSX, FreeBSD, NetBSD, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

max=0

# You can make this pattern more explicit if you like.
# Or you could add an `if` that verifies it and `continue`s the loop on failure.
# Or not you could just ignore the errors. :)
for fname in *.ZIP; do
  fname=${fname/.[0-9][0-9][0-9]/}    # strptime/strftime doesn't support ms...

  epoch=$(date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S%z.ZIP' "$fname" '+%s')
  if [ $epoch -gt $max ]; then
    max=$epoch
    latest="$fname"
  fi
done

echo "Latest: $latest"
```

This has the advantage of using a `for` loop, so it will not barf on filenames with special characters like newlines in them, in case you decide to expand the pattern to recognize such formats.

The other thing a `for` loop does for us is avoid a subshell to run `find`. This saves a minuscule amount of resources on your server.

Some provisos:

- If you need accuracy to less than a second, this solution will need extra tweaking.
- This [may not support dates after January 19th 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the key to doing what you want to do is parsing a valid `datestring` from the filename that can be used with the `date` command to find the **newest** file in the selection returned by `find`. To do this, you will need to write a small script as it will require more than a single command usable by `find ... -exec`.

**Note:** you did not provide a full filename, but I will assume that you mean something like `2015-09-01_10-48-09.941+0000.ZIP`

There are many ways to approach a small script to find the newest file based on the timestring. Using **parameter expansion** and **substring replacement** is what came to mind to handle creating a valid datestring to use with `date`. Each timestamp is then converted by date to `seconds since epoch` for comparison purposes:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i max=0

while read -r fname; do

    ## parese timestring from filename (assuming time.ZIP as filename)
    tmp="${fname%.ZIP}"
    t1=${tmp%_*}                    # first part (date)
    t2=${tmp#*_}                    # second part (time)
    dtstring="$t1 ${t2//-/:}"       # create date string, replace '-' with ':'
    tse=$(date -d "$dtstring" +%s)  # time (sec) since epoch
    if [ $tse -gt $max ]; then      # test for tse > max
        newest="$fname"             # save filename & update max
        max=$tse
    fi

done < <(find . -type f -name "*.ZIP" -printf "%f\n")

# just for testing
echo "max   : $max"
echo "newest: $newest"

## uncomment for actual copy
# cp "$newest" tempZIP
```

**Test Files**

```
$ ls -1 2015*
2015-08-31_10-48-09.941+0000.ZIP
2015-09-01_10-48-09.941+0000.ZIP
```

**Output**

```
$ bash neweststamp.sh
max   : 1441104489
newest: 2015-09-01_10-48-09.941+0000.ZIP
```

Try it before actually copying, then you can adjust and uncomment the actual copy.

**Note:** the parameter expansion and substring replacement are present in the advanced shells like bash. If you must limit it to the POSIX shell (old Bourne shell +), leave a comment and we can adjust the script (it will just get much longer)

**Deleting All Files EXCEPT Newest**

Continuing from your comment, once you have the newest file, you can use `find` once again to delete all of the other files in a given directory. Use the `!` not options along with `-name` (e.g. `! -name "$newest"`) to create a list excluding your newest file to delete:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f ! -name "$newest" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

You could also use a for loop as well:

```
for fname in /path/to/dir/*; do
    [ "$fname" != "$newest" ] && rm "$fname"
done
```

**Remember:** TEST with an `echo` or `printf` before you actually let the script remove anything. Examples:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f ! -name "$newest" -exec printf "rm %s\n" '{}' \;
```

or

```
for fname in /path/to/dir/*; do
    [ "$fname" != "$newest" ] && printf "rm %s\n" "$fname"
done
```

Fewer regrets that way...

Comment: To be clear, this solution will work in most Linux distros, but will fail in OSX, FreeBSD and other BSDs, because of the `-d` option to the `date` command.  In BSD-derived unices, you'd use the `-f` option to specify the input format of the date you wanted to convert. The OP hasn't mentioned his operating system, so it's important either to make the answer portable, or to note its limitations.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for the catch of `date -f`.

Comment: Ahh!  There are a number of reasons I would like to shoot apple. This is one. Why between Linux, FreeBSD, OSX, and the rest, we can't all just get the basics like `read`,, `date`, etc... to work the same simply escapes me `:p`. Look at ghoti's answer, it looks like he has it nailed down for OSX.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try and retrofit what ghoti did and see what i can come up with. I still don't know how to delete all files except the newest file in each subdirectory.

Comment: I added a full example of **Deleting All Files EXCEPT Newest** to the end of my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you. I'm having trouble with using find with printf because I'm on OSX. Do you have any suggestions to replace that? Also I should ask that before each time stamp there are the words: "LIVE_DATE_TIMESTAMP". How do I add that to the format? Will this grab only a single file being the newest in each subdirectory? I guess I"m a little confused about the formatting of the date string.

Comment: Uugh.. which part of find does OSX not have? `printf`? `newest`? It should be fairly standard. `find` is flexible enough that it will provide a work around, I'm just using `printf` to chop the path, so yes, there is an easy work around, but it will probably take a short script in addition to the `find`. Let me know and I'll take another look.

Comment: @Speakeasys if OSX has problems with `printf` in find, remember that is simply for testing purposes, the actual remove command would be `find /path/to/dir -type f ! -name "$newest" -exec rm '{}' \;` Put 4-5 files in a test directory and run the script with the updated `find` command on the test files and let me know how it goes.